# How do I serialize delegates in my WP7 application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, serialization, persistence

I am building an application for WP7. And I am working on the tombstoning part of my application.

And I have got a class such that

```
namespace packetq{
    public class Packet{
        int x;
        //some other information;
    }
}  

namespace packetq{
    public class PacketState{
        Packet A;
        func<Packet,Packet>   handler;
    }
}
```

Now I have a class which Instantiates Packet  object and assigns a handler to it.

when my application tombstones. I need to store this PacketState object so that When i restore it back I should be able to work on that  Packet  And I should be able to handle that Packet using that Handler.

So I need to serialize and persist that handler.

I read few articles it says that persistence and serialization could be done using Expression tree. But that way is really cumbersome.

Please suggest some other way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Since BinaryFormatter is not available, my advice would be: use a class instance (subclass of a common base-type) and a polymorphic method instead, perhaps using a decorator pattern. I don't know which serializer you are planning to use, but most can handle inheritance as long as the sub-types are known in advance.

So instead of a `Func<Packet,Packet>` you might have a `PacketHandler` base-class with a virtual method that accepts and returns `Packet`

To elaborate:

```
[DataContract, KnownType(typeof(EchoPacketHandler)]
public class PacketHandler {
    public virtual Packet Handle(Packet packet) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}
[DataContract]
public class EchoPacketHandler : PacketHandler {
    public override Packet Handle(Packet packet) { return packet; }
}
```

But add more subclasses, and state via [DataMember] as needed.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I am using DataContract Serializer. Can you please elaborate your answer I could not make much from it.